# PHP version changes the way to access data in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a difference in how I can access information in an Array in these PHP versions? Locally I run PHP version `5.5.3` and the following code gives expected output. On my remote server the PHP version is `5.3.22` and I get the an error.

test.php:

```
<?php
  function a($var){
    return [1, 2, 3][$var];
  }

  echo a(0);
?>
```

`5.5.3` output: 1

`5.3.22` output: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in test.php on line 3`

I can't find any changes in the PHP versions that would be so fundamental to make this break.

Comment: direct array access like that is a 5.4/5.5 thing. Check [5.4.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) under "General Improvements"

Comment: That array syntax was introduced in 5.4

Comment: Use array(1,2,3) in PHP5.3. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[1, 2, 3]` type syntax was only introduced in PHP 5.4

You have to use array() in 5.3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer because of the alternative solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, [PHP 5.4 introduced shorthand array syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89) `[]` (to create a new array) as well as shorthand array referencing.

Comment: it was introduced in 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference in how array literals work in php 5.5.  PHP 5.3 does NOT support array literals.

[PHP Array Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the straightforward answer mentioned by others that the alternative array syntax was introduced in [PHP 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), and you need to use `array()`, it is worth pointing out that, where possible, your development and production environments should match.

This may require setting up a virtual machine with the same OS as you have on production, in order to obtain the same versions of PHP/MySQL and whatever else you are using, to test your code in as close to a like for like environment as possible.

Even if you had a unit test, run locally before deployment, you would not have been able to catch this issue. It may not be costly on this occasion but it is worth taking the time to prepare against a more severe issue arising in the future from the inconsistencies between environments.

Essentially, this is all geared towards avoiding the classic "it works on my machine".